# Can't get Vim to bring in dictionary; fails with this message '-- Definition completion (^D^N^P) Pattern not found'

Tags: vim

I have install `YCM` in `Vim` and `<c-x><c-f>` for file completion works well. Also I get proper completions for code.

But just noticed that trying to access *dictionary* seems to fails, when using: `<c-x><c-d>`. I just get the following displayed:

`-- Definition completion (^D^N^P) Pattern not found`

**Vim version**:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Apr 21 2014 14:54:22)
MacOS X (unix) version
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the output of `:set dictionary?`?

Comment: Yup! It was empty! Just fixed it. If you can post a quick answer, I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<C-x><C-d>` is "definition completion". It works if the language you work with has an "include" mechanism and Vim is set up to follow includes and to recognize "definitions" for that language.

See:

```
:help i_ctrl-x_ctrl-d
:help 'include'
:help 'definition'
```

Dictionary completion is `<C-x><C-k>` and requires the `'dictionary'` option to point to at least one dictionary:

```
set dictionary=/path/to/dict
```

See:

```
:help i_ctrl-x_ctrl-k
:help 'dictionary'
```